# Is there a way to resize a QAction

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

The `QAction` inside a `QToolBar` is away bigger than the icon I am using (16x16 or 32x32). How to resize a `QAction` to fit an icon without extra space. I tried to subclass, but I could find a method for the `QAction` to resize.

```
class MyAction(QAction):
    def __init__(self)
    super().__init__()
```

I tried to use `setIconSize(QSize(32,32))`, but it is not affecting the `QAction` it self. I believe this is related to the app stylesheet I am using, but I don't want to change that.
My current solution is to use a `QToolButton`, and `addWidget` inside the `QToolBar()`, is there better way ?

I am simply using a `QMainWindow`:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self._Bar_1 = self.addToolBar('bar_1')
        self._Bar_1.setIconSize(QSize(41, 41))
        act1 = QAction(QIcon(r'icons\exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        self._Bar_1.addAction(act1)
```

I can't take a snapshot cause I need to hover or click the action to show its size, but it looks like this. I believe it is related  to the stylesheet I am using:

[image]

This is ascrren shot I could get. notice, when hovering or press on the `QAction` in the first ToolBar, the action is seems too big for the icon inside ! Hope it helps

[image]

I am using the `qt_material` , find the link https://github.com/UN-GCPDS/qt-material

Comment: A QToolBar doesn't host an actual QAction, but a QToolButton that represents it. Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "bigger", also providing a screenshot and a basic [mre]?

Comment: I have add an image showing, how it looks when hovering or pressing the action. The `QAction` look as big as this, and the icon is small inside. I want to get rid of this extra space from the `QAction` to the icon

Comment: That's not really useful, we need an actual screenshot *and* the icon in order to understand and eventually *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: I have added a shot. Hope it helps. I can't get better. Note: when hovering at the first `QAction`, the action is seems too big for the icon inside (shadow) !

Comment: There are free programs that can take screenshots after a certain delay. Then, where is the icon? And the stylesheet?

Comment: I have added a link to the stylesheet I am using, and the icon. I believe it's related to the stylesheet

Comment: That's a very extended and complex stylesheet management. I'd look into https://github.com/UN-GCPDS/qt-material/blob/master/qt_material/material.css.template and eventually contact the maintainer.